# MongoDB Atlas Trigger Events: How to handle a burst of events

Tags: mongodb, triggers

I am looking to use app services to trigger a function whenever a product inside my database changes.

However, there can be a burst of triggers. My web app has an autosave feature when creating/editing products. The product can change many times in one minute.

Is there a way to only run the most recent trigger event out of all trigger events with the same object ID within say 3 minutes? It is okay if it is slightly delayed.

The link to the documentation is here:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/triggers/database-triggers/